# How to get continuous graphs in Highstock (beta release)

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I have a question about the product Highstock (beta release), http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock

For anyone who has experience with using this or feels they can answer, please!!!

I am noticing that sometimes the software will connect to data points even though there is missing data between then. This is a great feature because it give the sense of continuity despite actually missing data... But sometimes, they are gaps.. I haven't been able to located the exact setting that is responsible for this.. If anyone knows how to achieve continuous graphs, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: I would really like to know as well...

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you want the data plotted continuously instead of evenly spaced, you can set the "ordinal" option of the axis to false.  See details here:  http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#xAxis--ordinal

Answer (score 1):

add NULL as data point - not 0 and use the connectNulls option